# Regex to select only value inside tags

Tags: java, regex

I have some emails in this format:

```
name of the person <emailoftheperson@someemail.com>
name of another person <emailoftheanotherperson@someemail.com>
```

I would like to have a regex expression that would select only the elements inside the tags, along with the tags.. the above input would result in this output:

```
<emailoftheperson@someemail.com>
<emailoftheanotherperson@someemail.com>
```

I would like the regex go work along with Java

Comment: Assuming there's no `<` or `>` elsewhere in your string: `<.*>`

Comment: @timolawl this would match everything between the first `<` and the last `>`, cause regex is greedy and `.*` will consume everything (`>` as well) in between. https://regex101.com/r/gV9uN5/1 (don't rely on line breaks)

Comment: Try this expression `String tagregex = "<(.*?)>";`

Comment: @dognose Right. It's a simple solution if OPs case happens to be simple. I'm aware of that, which is why I prefaced my solution with "assuming there's no `<` or `>` elsewhere". OP can add the `?` to specify the regex to be reluctant, if it contains more than one email in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the expression `<[^>]*>` to match everything that was within a single pair of angled braces :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// Define your regex
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>");
// Get your matches
Matcher m = regex.matcher("{your-input-here}");
// Iterate through your matches
while(m.find()){
    // Output each match
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

You can [see a working example of this here](https://ideone.com/fork/8Vb9Ts).

Answer (score 1):

The question as been well answered already, but another option is using `<.*?>`, i.e:

```
String text = "name of the person <emailoftheperson@someemail.com> name of another person <emailoftheanotherperson@someemail.com>";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<.*?>");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(text);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(0));
}
```

---

**Demos:**

[Java Demo](http://ideone.com/dUPSzP)

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN2aA4/1)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
<.*?>
    < matches the characters < literally
    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
    > matches the characters > literally
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Rion answered first so I have to give it to him, anyway, good work with the demos and the regex explanation, thanks a lot